# Issues displaying image from JSON query

Tags: jquery, html, json, image

I'm trying to display an image based on a file string I am receiving off a JSON query (in the style of {"itemIcon":"http://www.example.com/image.png"}.

The error I am receiving is:

```
[Error] TypeError: http://www.example.com/image.png is not a valid argument for 'in'     (evaluating '( length - 1 ) in obj')
isArraylike (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 997)
each (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 632)
(anonymous function) (main.js, line 9)
fire (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 3048)
fireWith (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 3160)
done (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 8235)
callback (jquery-1.10.2.js, line 8778)
```

My js is as follows:

```
function getItemIcon (itemID)
{
var jsonURL = 'http://example.com/rest/XXXX/items/' + itemID + '?fields=
itemIcon&id_Field=itemID&app_name=XXXX';

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json)
{
    var imgURL = "";

    $.each(json.itemIcon, function() {
        imgURL += '<li><img src= "' + this.imgURL + '"></li';
    });
})
}
```

The HTML section looks like this:

```
<body onload="getItemIcon('1')">

<div id="itemIcon">here</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.itemIcon` is a string representing the image URL, so `$.each(json.itemIcon` is attempting to loop over every letter in that string and throwing an error

You don't need an `each` unless you have an array of objects that isn't shown.

This should work based on information given

```
var imgURL = '<li><img src= "' + json.itemIcon + '"></li>';
```